# Portable Cocoa for Windows

Tags: xcode, windows, cocoa, portability

So Im working on a project in Xcode and would like to also be able to work on it on my PC work laptop when travelling. Is there anything I could run off of a USB?

Comment: plz free to accept and tick the answer if you are satisfied :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit all of the text files using a normal text editor, like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/). I don't think that there's any software for Windows that can edit all of the different things you would have in your project, like the `.xib` files and such.

Comment: This would be an ideal solution, but im a rank amateur...so coding without it correcting me would lead to terrible code haha

Comment: Well this looks like it might be the only viable solution ATM.

Answer (score 1):

You can try installing Mac OS in your PC!!!
Many of my friends have installed dual Mac OS X Mountain Lion & Mac OS X Mountain-Lion in their Intel Based PC using VMWare 9 and its running fine. But I tried with no success as I am using AMD Processor.

Comment: This would be ideal, but its my work computer and I don't have admin rights :(

Comment: ok...then no other way... even in notepad you cant see .h/.m files in correct formatted. They look jumbled and reading becomes very difficult. it will take 30 minutes to format and bring it to readable format!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you were ambitious you could try gnustep, but that is pretty tough to set up on cigwin,  and would only be a very close fit for Mac OS X and not  iOS.

Comment: Im only looking to work on OSX so thats ok. After a quick google it looks like there might are a couple portable builds of cigwin. Ill see if I can get gnustep running on that :)

Comment: gnustep is not an option -- it fails to 'emulate'/replicate large portions of cocoa (especially AppKit)

Comment: i guess it depends on your target, if you are targeting 10.5 or earlier.. it works great, if you plan on doing cool new stuff then, yeah not great.

Comment: ya unfortunately im looking for new stuff :P